# XStream Exception

Tags: java, xml, serialization, constructor, xstream

Writing an object to an XML file using XStream and getting the following error while reading the File.

Point to be noted that CompareBean is an Object in the Main Object that I am writing to the XML file

```
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: Cannot construct beans.CompareBean as it does not have a no-args constructor : Cannot construct beans.CompareBean as it does not have a no-args constructor
```

Comment: Does it have a no-args constructor? Is it an inner class?

Comment: i created a no-args constructor, then I got this error :     com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: Could not call java.text.DecimalFormat.readObject() : Could not call java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.readObject() :  : ParseError at [row,col]:[1,4081]
Message: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence. :  : ParseError at [row,col]:[1,4081]
Message: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
---- Debugging information ----
message             :  : ParseError at [row,col]:[1,4081]